# ASP.NET MVC application security

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Today i test my ASP.NET MVC web-application and i find out anyone can easily submit a form of our website without coming on my website?

Ex: `example.com/home/test`

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Test(string name)
{
    return View("home");
}  

<form id="myForm" method="post" action="example.com/home/test">
    <input type="text" name="name" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

if other website make this form that when user fill the form that my website will be affect.

Are i can check the request made by user through my website or other.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you may be looking for some Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF) help. ASP.NET MVC has a pretty simple tool to help with that:

If you include: `<%= Html.AntiForgeryToken() %>` inside the form that is being submitted then you can mark your action method with the `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` attribute and have a pretty good handle on stopping CSRF attacks. Don't take my word for it, check out Steve Sanderson's [old] blog post about it and it should have all the background and information you'll need.

http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2008/09/01/prevent-cross-site-request-forgery-csrf-using-aspnet-mvcs-antiforgerytoken-helper/

Comment: it is not worked? i am run two both application on localhost and both make a same forgery key

Comment: @steven It uses the machine key, which would be the same in both cases.

Answer (score 5):

Use the `[Authorize]` filter to prevent anonymous users from accessing controllers or actions.

http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2009/04/09/CustomAuthorizationASPNETMVCFrameworkAuthorizeAttribute.aspx

Comment: it is not worked i am use my own login system. when i test from many application he redirect to /account/login. and he not stop accepting second application request

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question. DM's answer is spot on.

Answer (score 1):

Steven, I can recommend you to watch the video:
[The HaaHa Show: Microsoft ASP.NET MVC Security with Haack and Hanselman](http://live.visitmix.com/MIX10/Sessions/FT05)

After 24 minutes they discuss how to protect a MVC site with the `Html.AntiForgery` tag and show how you can implement this in a MVC website.

Answer (score 0):

steven,

in addition to the suggestions above (which for the life of me, i can't understand why they work CS). anyway, additionally, you can examine the origin of the request inside the controller:

```
var origReq = HttpContext.Request.UrlReferrer;
```

or, examine the headers and determine your 'action' based on the contents:

```
var headers = HttpContext.Request.Headers;
```

**[edit]** - of course, 'headers' can be tampered with (depending on how determined someone was to x'post to your site), so you could probably only use these for informational purposes - it's not a 100% certainty...

you can then decide if this 'post' is allowed or not depending on whether it originated from your domain (or a domain that is approved) or not.

jim

Comment: grr - got me legs chopped off there for suggesting ADDITIONAL checks that could be made. i'll get me coat and keep my mouth shut in future :-)... good luck all... and some nice comments too by all, especially bzlm

Comment: DM -you're a real gent, hope i didn't sound like i was begging :-). thanks, those '-1's never look good.... all the best again